# Basic ArrayList in a RecyclerView not giving the expected output

Tags: android

I need someone to tell me what is the basic required libraries for a basic app that has displays an arraylist in a recyclerview.
I implemented all the steps and there is no error on the android studio, but the app didn't show a "Strings" from the array i passed to the adapter,  it only shows numbers from 1 to 20 with out any letters.
this is the main activity file

```
package com.android.a0202;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    /*
     * References to RecyclerView and Adapter to reset the list to its
     * "pretty" state when the reset menu item is clicked.
     */
    private GreenAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView mNumbersList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          final String[]  NUM_LIST_ITEMS = new String[20];
        NUM_LIST_ITEMS[0]="8451";
        NUM_LIST_ITEMS[1]="85";
        NUM_LIST_ITEMS[2]="852";
        NUM_LIST_ITEMS[3]="526585";
        NUM_LIST_ITEMS[4]="84565";
        NUM_LIST_ITEMS[7]="rctvybun";
        NUM_LIST_ITEMS[8]="zxctvybunmi";
        NUM_LIST_ITEMS[9]="drtyuhi";
        NUM_LIST_ITEMS[10]="xerctvybunm";
        NUM_LIST_ITEMS[11]="ercvtyn";
        NUM_LIST_ITEMS[12]="lkxghj";
        NUM_LIST_ITEMS[13]="85";
        NUM_LIST_ITEMS[14]="534546";
        NUM_LIST_ITEMS[15]="454645";
        NUM_LIST_ITEMS[16]="xcvbnj";
        NUM_LIST_ITEMS[17]="cv";
        NUM_LIST_ITEMS[18]="cvb";
        NUM_LIST_ITEMS[19]="/";


        /*
         * Using findViewById, we get a reference to our RecyclerView from xml. This allows us to
         * do things like set the adapter of the RecyclerView and toggle the visibility.
         */
        mNumbersList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_numbers);
        /*
         * A LinearLayoutManager is responsible for measuring and positioning item views within a
         * RecyclerView into a linear list. This means that it can produce either a horizontal or
         * vertical list depending on which parameter you pass in to the LinearLayoutManager
         * constructor. By default, if you don't specify an orientation, you get a vertical list.
         * In our case, we want a vertical list, so we don't need to pass in an orientation flag to
         * the LinearLayoutManager constructor.
         *
         * There are other LayoutManagers available to display your data in uniform grids,
         * staggered grids, and more! See the developer documentation for more details.
         */
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mNumbersList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        /*
         * Use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes in content do not
         * change the child layout size in the RecyclerView
         */
        mNumbersList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        /*
         * The GreenAdapter is responsible for displaying each item in the list.
         */
        mAdapter = new GreenAdapter(NUM_LIST_ITEMS);
        mNumbersList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

}
```

and this is the adapter file

```
  package com.android.a0202;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class GreenAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GreenAdapter.NumberViewHolder> {

//    final private ListItemClickListener monClicklistener;
    // TODO (1) Create a layout resource in res/layout/ called number_list_item.xml

    // Do steps 2 - 11 within number_list_item.xml
    // TODO (2) Make the root layout a FrameLayout
    // TODO (3) Make the width match_parent and the height wrap_content
    // TODO (4) Set the padding to 16dp
    // TODO (5) Add a TextView as the only child of the FrameLayout
    // TODO (6) Give the TextView an ID "@+id/tv_item_number"
    // TODO (7) Set the height and width to wrap_content
    // TODO (8) Align the TextView to the start of the parent
    // TODO (9) Center the TextView vertically in the layout
    // TODO (10) Set the font family to monospace
    // TODO (11) Set the text size to 42sp

    private static final String TAG = GreenAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private String[] mNumberItems;



 //   public interface ListItemClickListener {
   //     void onListItemClick(int clickedItemIndex);

    //}



    /**
     * Constructor for GreenAdapter that accepts a number of items to display and the specification
     * for the ListItemClickListener.
     *
     * @param numberOfItems Number of items to display in list
     */
    public GreenAdapter(String[] numberOfItems) {
        mNumberItems = numberOfItems;
    //    monClicklistener =listener;
    }

    /**
     *
     * This gets called when each new ViewHolder is created. This happens when the RecyclerView
     * is laid out. Enough ViewHolders will be created to fill the screen and allow for scrolling.
     *
     * @param viewGroup The ViewGroup that these ViewHolders are contained within.
     * @param viewType  If your RecyclerView has more than one type of item (which ours doesn't) you
     *                  can use this viewType integer to provide a different layout. See
     *
     *                  for more details.
     * @return A new NumberViewHolder that holds the View for each list item
     */
    @Override
    public NumberViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        Context context = viewGroup.getContext();
        int layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.number_list_item;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        boolean shouldAttachToParentImmediately = false;

        View view = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, viewGroup, shouldAttachToParentImmediately);
        NumberViewHolder viewHolder = new NumberViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    /**
     * OnBindViewHolder is called by the RecyclerView to display the data at the specified
     * position. In this method, we update the contents of the ViewHolder to display the correct
     * indices in the list for this particular position, using the "position" argument that is conveniently
     * passed into us.
     *
     * @param holder   The ViewHolder which should be updated to represent the contents of the
     *                 item at the given position in the data set.
     * @param position The position of the item within the adapter's data set.
     */
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NumberViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "#" + position);
        holder.bind(position);
    }

    /**
     * This method simply returns the number of items to display. It is used behind the scenes
     * to help layout our Views and for animations.
     *
     * @return The number of items available in our forecast
     */
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return 20;
    }

    public class NumberViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
   // implements View.OnClickListener
    {

       private TextView listItemNumberView ;
        public NumberViewHolder (View itemView){
            super(itemView);
           listItemNumberView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_number);
        }
        void bind (int listIndex){
            listItemNumberView.setText(String.valueOf(listIndex));
        }
      //  @Override
        //public void onClick(View view){
          //  int clickedPosition = getAdapterPosition();
           // monClicklistener.onListItemClick(clickedPosition);

        }


    }
    // TODO (12) Create a class called NumberViewHolder that extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder

    // TODO (13) Within NumberViewHolder, create a TextView variable called listItemNumberView

    // TODO (14) Create a constructor for NumberViewHolder that accepts a View called itemView as a parameter
    // TODO (15) Within the constructor, call super(itemView) and then find listItemNumberView by ID

    // TODO (16) Within the NumberViewHolder class, create a void method called bind that accepts an int parameter called listIndex
    // TODO (17) Within bind, set the text of listItemNumberView to the listIndex
    // TODO (18) Be careful to get the String representation of listIndex, as using setText with an int does something different
```

Comment: If there are no errors before compiling, missing libraries are not the problem. If it crashes when you run it, you should look at the log when it runs to see why.

Comment: Copy paste the log with your question so that we can know what the problem is.

Comment: @DavidInnocent     i fixed the first problem, there is another problem appears, please help me here

Answer (score 0):

You should change the following line.

```
listItemNumberView.setText(String.valueOf(listIndex));
```

To the following:

```
listItemNumberView.setText(mNumberItems[listIndex]);
```

You didn't get the specific item from the list.

Try it.